# rsync: delete folder or directory from rsync daemon module

Tags: rsync

A server I'm working on has a rsync module "foo". So I can view the available files on it as follows:

```
rsync -rltvz 10.100.100.1::foo
receiving incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x       20480 2013/05/30 17:43:34 .
drwxrwxr-x        4096 2012/06/15 03:00:30 BAR
```

What command can I use to delete folder BAR from the server? There is a --remove-source-files option, but what I need is "--remove-source-directories"

I've searched for examples of how to do this, but everything I've found assumes that the source is mounted on the local file system.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I've found is to make the desired changes locally then rsync in the opposite direction.

```
# Copy files to local machine
rsync -rltvz 10.100.100.1::foo .
# Delete the folder I don't want locally
rmdir BAR
# Rsync in the opposite direction:
rsync --delete --force -rltvz . 10.100.100.1::foo
```